# How to fix Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm creating a web application using spring-boot with annotation based configuration.

At first, I created a spring application with annotation based config using Hibernate and JPA. It was working fine but then I needed to add spring-boot to my application and now cannot start it. Here is the code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Runner.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScans(value = { @ComponentScan("com.alex.pharm.dao"),
        @ComponentScan("com.alex.pharm.service") })
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean geEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("LOCAL_PERSISTENCE");
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(type = "JpaTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager geJpaTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(geEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }
}
```

```
    <groupId>com.sachatol.pharmacy</groupId>
    <artifactId>pharmacyWebStore</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency><!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate 5.2.9 Final -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

But when I try to run it I get the following exception:

```
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization
 - cancelling refresh attempt:org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' 
defined in class path resource
 [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.obtainApplicationContext()
Lorg/springframework/context/ApplicationContext;
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue found - I used the old version for spring-context in pom (4.3.7.RELEASE) which override the one that spring-boot has and was the reason of NoSuchMethodError. So spring-context dependency was old and obsolete after removing or changing it to newer version (5.0.3) application started fine

Answer (score 0):

Your **@RequestMapping** seems missing some parts, try with something like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your request mapping, you have incorrectly used :
`@RequestMapping("/")`

Instead, use this mapping to specify the end-point and the request-method like this : 
`@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens if you have two methods with same request mapping values. Make sure you have unique RequestMapping values.